# How to log the pom.xml property changes with every release?

Tags: git, maven, logging, pom.xml

I wan to log the changes done in pom.xml properties tag while releasing next release tag. Any lead would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please give more details what you like to do ?

Comment: During a release process usually you only change the versions of the project...and not properties for dependencies etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the changes between the last commit and your actual work, then just diff it.

`git diff pom.xml`

If you want to see all the changes since the file has been created, you can use gitk.

`gitk pom.xml`

This last thing will display you all the changes and commit around this file.

**EDIT**

`git log --follow -p -- pom.xml >> log.txt`

This will log all your changes on *pom.xml* file in a *log.txt* file.

Comment: This is one of the way, What I want is to log the pom.xml properties changes. For example, if pom.xml contains a property "app.version" 4.0.2 and in next release version, it contains 4.0.3 then it should detect it and logs it into the file.

Comment: A plugin for the same would be great.

Comment: Not sure to well understand your question then.
A simple ```git status``` will indicate you that a change has been done in pom.xml.
In example, if "app.version" changes from 4.0.2 to 4.0.3, ```git status``` will display you this change in your repository

Comment: The requirement is that I want to log this change automatically when maven builds the project. Is there any way for the same?

Comment: You can use a git client like *SourceTree* or *GitKraken*

Comment: Thanks but I want to automate the process of logging the changes in pom.xml so that with every release there will be a log file which will have the information regrading the components that had been changed.

Comment: I don't know if you can do this.

If you want to save these changes in a log file, this will work

```git log --follow -p -- pom.xml >> log.txt```

But you have to do it manualy. Or maybe write a script that will watch pom.xml changes or which will be executed after each maven build

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I figured that I need to write custom plugin to track the specific property and generate the log which will states that "xyz" component has been changed or updated.

Comment: Indeed, depending of your editor, you will need to write an automatic script that will be triggered after each build.
Concerning your main ask, I think this is solved, you can confirm my answer if you're ok with